# "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))" in 64 bit OS

Tags: c#, .net

We developed one windows application using VS 2005 with framework 2.0. This application is running perfectly on 32 bit Operating System. Now we need to give support for 64 bit OS.

While working with 64 bit Operating System we are getting the below error message.

> "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))".

Following is the code block

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Driver));     
this.axDriver = new AxCCNAccess.AxDriver();     
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(axDriver)).BeginInit();     
SuspendLayout();     
//     
// axDriver     
//    
axDriver .Enabled = true;   
axDriver .Location = new System.Drawing.Point(241, 211);   
axDriver .Name = "axDriver ";    
axDriver .OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axDriver .OcxState")));    
axDriver .Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 42);     
axDriver .TabIndex = 0;     
//     
// Driver     
//     
AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);    
AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;     
ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);     
Controls.Add(axDriver );   
Name = "DriverContainer";  
Text = "DriverContainer";     
try     
{
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(axDriver )).EndInit(); 
}    
catch (Exception ex)  
{
string sss = ex.Message;
}
ResumeLayout(false);
```

Getting issue in the try block.

Comment: You are trying to embed a 32-bit ocx in a 64-bit application.
Your application will probably run just fine if you force to run as a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS ... project properties -> build -> Platform Target = x86

Comment: 7 year old long shot, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem for your side, because i uninstall one software in that ocx is removed, till that time another one software did not working fine, after that i register

> RICHTX32.ocx or RICHTX64.ocx

(with your system bit version 32 or 64) now working fine. i think it will help.